# System.Net.WebException: 'Failed to connect to /192.168.8.100:5001'

Tags: c#, android, xamarin.forms

i want to connect my xamarin app with asp.net mvc core 3.1 localhost server https://192.168.8.100:5001/api/products/

Here **192.168.8.100** is ip address of my computer and **5001** is the asp.net localhost port number

> MainPage.xaml.cs

```
private const string Url = "https://192.168.8.100:5001/api/products/";
private HttpClient _client = new HttpClient();
private ObservableCollection<Product> _posts;

public Product()
{
    InitializeComponent();
}

protected override async void OnAppearing()
{
    var context = await _client.GetStringAsync(Url);
    var post = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<IEnumerable<Product>>(context);

    _posts = new ObservableCollection<Product>(post);

    listView.ItemsSource = _posts;
}
```

After excuting the **var context = await _client.GetStringAsync(Url)**, line it show me exception.

> Exception

```
System.Net.WebException: 'Failed to connect to /192.168.8.100:5001'
```

Comment: Are you debugging this on your device or using the emulator ?

Comment: try to use Curl , postman or something similar to try to fetch/post to your API first, see whether it's connected?

Comment: If you are using the emulator this address will not work

Comment: i am using the emulator

Comment: Now when i run the app in real device it shows me another exception. System.OperationCanceledException: 'The operation was canceled.'

Answer (score 1):

If you want to refer to the computer which is running the *Android Emulator*, use the *IP address* `10.0.2.2` instead. You can read more from [here](https://developer.android.com/studio/run/emulator-networking.html).

> Each instance of the emulator runs behind a virtual router/firewall
>   service that isolates it from your development machine network
>   interfaces and settings and from the internet. An emulated device
>   can't see your development machine or other emulator instances on the
>   network. Instead, it sees only that it is connected through Ethernet
>   to a router/firewall.
>
> The virtual router for each instance manages the 10.0.2/24 network
>   address space — all addresses managed by the router are in the form of
>   10.0.2.xx, where xx is a number.

Furthermore

> 10.0.2.2 is a Special alias to your host loopback interface (i.e., 127.0.0.1 on your development machine)

Comment: thank you for you quick reply, i tried this technique but now this time different exception is showing

Comment: @MalikHaseeb that's a good sign. However now you have to ask another question